# Will God ever forgive me for taking my cousin's virginity?

Tags: homosexuality, zina, forgiveness

I've made a really bad mistake and I know it. I don't know if Allah will forgive me. I'm a girl and my cousin is also a girl, and I took her virginity and I feel like dying because I know what I did was wrong, and after I done that I really hope God will forgive me.  Will He ever forgive me?  What do I have to do to have his forgiveness? Please don't judge me, I've learned from my mistake and I will never do anything like that ever again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its opinion based. Will Allah forgive you? How are we supposed to know? That is His decision. Allah does forgive sins when a person sincerely repents. See [Quran 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53) and [4:48](https://quran.com/4/48) and  [42:25](https://quran.com/42/25)

Answer (score 1):

Allah says:

> “Say: O my Servants who have transgressed against their souls! Despair
>   not of the Mercy of Allah: for Allah forgives all sins: for He is
>   Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful.” [[Sûrah al-Zumar: 53](https://quran.com/39/53)]
>
> [25:68-69](https://quran.com/25/68-69) “And those who invoke not any other ilah (god) along
>   with Allah, nor kill such a person as Allah has forbidden, except for
>   just cause, nor commit illegal sexual intercourse and whoever does
>   this shall receive the punishment.The torment will be doubled for him
>   on the Day of Resurrection, and he will abide therein in disgrace;
>
> [25:70](https://quran.com/25/70) Except those who repent and believe (in Islamic
>   Monotheism), and do righteous deeds; for those, Allah will change
>   their sins into good deeds, and Allah is Oft‑Forgiving, Most
>   Merciful.”

Based on these verses, no sin is too great for Allah to forgive for the one who repents.

This Hadith also clarifies it.

> Al-Tirmidhi narrated that Anas ibn Malik (may Allah be pleased with
>   him) said: I heard the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of
>   Allah be upon him) say:
>
> “Allah, may He be blessed and exalted, said:
>
> " O son of Adam, so long as you call upon Me and ask of Me,    I shall
>   forgive you for what you have done, and I shall not mind.    O son of
>   Adam, were your sins to reach the clouds of the sky and were you then
>   to ask forgiveness of Me, I would forgive you and I would not mind. "
>
> [[Saheeh al-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/48/171)]

So Allah will forgive your sins if your repent sincerely and do good for taking away your sins.